# WebAPI POST, service always receiving null

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I've been searching for hours about this problem but I can't seem to find any answer anywhere

I have built an ASP.NET WebAPI that accepts JSON GET/POST requests and it works A1 when I use fiddler or advanced rest client extension for google chrome.

Now I have to take an existing android application and modify it to work with my WebAPI. I've cleared all the junk I did not need to make it easier but I still can't POST.
GET works fine, I receive my response string and everything is fine, but the POST returns a 400 Bad Request.

My webApi controller expects a ProblemReports object. ProblemReports has been made by me and it goes like this :

```
    public class ProblemReports
{
    [Key]
    public int problem_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Nullable<int> request_type { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Nullable<int> problem_type_id { get; set; }
    public String picture_url { get; set; }
    public contact_information contact_information { get; set; }
    public problem_location problem_location { get; set; }
    public bool dog_on_property { get; set; }

}
```

with subclasses

```
    public class problem_location
{
    public String street { get; set; }
    public String city { get; set; }
    public int relative_position_id { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
    public class contact_information
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String phone { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code for my android POST in my service handler class
The funny part of this is that I can put a breakpoint before sending my json string to the StringEntity, copy the raw json string, paste it in the BODY section advanced rest client, fill the headers, hit post and boom : Response is 200 OK

If I breakpoint my WebAPI on the controller, I can see that when sending the request via Advanced rest client, I can access problemreports, but if I break it on my android app's request, problemreports is null

```
public static String POST(String url, ProblemReports report) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";

    if (report.picture_url == null)
    {
        report.picture_url = "no picture";
    }
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        String json = "";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("request_type", report.request_type);
        jsonObject.accumulate("problem_type_id", report.problem_type_id);
        jsonObject.accumulate("picture_url", report.picture_url);

        JSONObject contact_informationObject = new JSONObject();
        contact_informationObject.accumulate("name",
                report.contact_information.name);
        contact_informationObject.accumulate("phone",
                report.contact_information.phone);
        jsonObject.accumulate("contact_information",
                contact_informationObject);

        JSONObject problem_locationObject = new JSONObject();
        problem_locationObject.accumulate("street",
                report.problem_location.street);
        problem_locationObject.accumulate("city",
                report.problem_location.city);
        problem_locationObject.accumulate("latitude",
                report.problem_location.latitude);
        problem_locationObject.accumulate("longitude",
                report.problem_location.longitude);
        problem_locationObject.accumulate("relative_position_id",
                report.problem_location.relative_position_id);
        jsonObject.accumulate("problem_location", problem_locationObject);

        jsonObject.accumulate("dog_on_property", report.dog_on_property);

        json = jsonObject.toString();
        //String otherJson = "{ProblemReports: " + json + "}";
        //I saw on the web to add ProblemReports: but it doensn't work

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        httpPost.setHeader(
                "Authorization",
                "Bearer TokenRemovedBecauseUseless");


        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        if (inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "InputStream convert fail!!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e.getCause().toString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is the raw JSON string made from my app. That actual string works fine on Fiddler or advanced rest client

```
{
"contact_information":
{
    "phone":"6666666666",
    "name":"fiber"
},
"dog_on_property":false,
"problem_type_id":3,
"request_type":1,
"problem_location":
{
    "longitude":1234,
    "latitude":1234,
    "relative_position_id":0,
    "city":"Montreal, QC A1A 1A1",
    "street":"0000 René-Lévesque Blvd"
}
```

}

I have no idea about what is going on here, any help/tip/advice will do.
I've set my controller to throw any errors and the only thing I get is 400 BAD REQUEST

Here the post portion of my controller for

```
 // POST api/ProblemReports
    [ResponseType(typeof(ProblemReports))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostProblemReports([FromBody]ProblemReports problemreports)
    {
        var allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, this.ModelState));
          //  return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try
        {
            db.ProblemReports.Add(problemreports);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Ok(ex);
        }


        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = problemreports.problem_id }, problemreports);
        ReturnID ri = new ReturnID(problemreports.problem_id);
        return Ok(ri);
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the relevant portion of the WebApi controller?

Comment: Found the problem, my StringEntity should have been

     StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8");

Ill post this as an answer tomorrow as I need to wait 8 hours before answering my own questions. Thanks for you time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer to my problems. Took 4 hours to find that little error but here it goes :

I had the line

```
 httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

and the string entity

```
 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
```

It needed to be

```
 httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
```

And

```
 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8");
```

Boom everything works fine, sorry for bothering anybody thanks for reading and have a nice day